# ClearCase: Stream maintenance

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Who can lock/unlock/obsolete streams (or any other object) in a clearcase project? Do you have to be a privilaged user to perform these operations on streams that you didn't create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cleartool lock` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) does mention:

- unix: type/object owner, VOB owner, root
- Windows: type/object owner, VOB owner, member of the ClearCase administrators group (which is the "privilege user": see "[About ClearCase privileged users on Windows](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146253)")

> `ClearCase privileged user` is a designation referring to a user account that is a member of the `clearcase` group, which is granted ClearCase administrator rights when working in Full ClearCase.
>   Members of the `clearcase` group are granted special ClearCase rights.

Regarding Stream, a `lock -obsolete Stream:xxx` might be your only way to "remove" a Stream (especially if baselines were already created on it): see "[Removing a UCM stream that has a delivered baseline](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146297)".

[Here are some examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136290) for locking multiple instances of a same type of object.

To be sure a lock has actually worked, [use the `-fmt "%n %[locked]p\n"`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117300) format when listing Streams:

```
cleartool lsstream -obsolete -fmt "%n %[locked]p\n" -invob vob
```

---

The [OP Raihan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959263/raihan) adds in the comments:

> According to the ClearCase documentation it it recommended to lock a stream before creating a baseline to prevent users from delivering during the process.
>   Isn't it overkill for a 'Project Manager' or 'Integrator' to have the root privilege who is managing a single UCM project (not necessarily created by him)?

Two things:

- one, that means locking a stream with the -nuser option, in order to allow the integrator to perform operations (like making a baseline) on that stream.
- two, if the integrator is not the owner an in... "integration" stream, then he/she asks the ClearCase administrator to give him/her the ownership of said Stream.

```
cleartool protect -chown integratorLogin stream:aStream@\aPVob
```

Comment: According to the clearcase documentation it is recommended to lock a stream before creating a baseline to prevent users from delivering during the process. Isn't it overkill for a 'Project Manager' or 'Integrator' to have the `root` privilage who is managing a single UCM project (not necessarily created by him)?

Comment: Thank you. So that means there can't be more than one integrator managing the same UCM project.

Comment: @Raihan: correct, especially when it comes to locking a Stream. For other operations, you have some extended policies like https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147119 (`POLICY_CHSTREAM_UNRESTRICTED`), but it isn't for locking operations.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I remember, you have to be one of the following:

- Stream owner/creator
- VOB owner
- Member of ClearCase group
- root (in UNIX \ Linux)

You may get further details by `cleartool man lock`

Comment: What is `ClearCase group`? Is it a OS user group?